# Find Unique in google sheets - first n characters

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet with a column (A) of urls.

```
Xttps://tXco/008wnbebbw
Xttps://tXco/00lR1FNKBo
Xttps://tXco/00lR1Fw9cO
Xttps://tXco/00UwZwgh2h
Xttps://tXco/00UwZwxSqR
Xttps://tXco/00UwZwxSqR
Xttps://tXco/044TcIFl72
```

In column B I need to find all unique urls up to the 18th character. For instance column B should show:

```
Xttps://tXco/008wnbebbw
Xttps://tXco/00lR1FNKBo
Xttps://tXco/00UwZwgh2h
Xttps://tXco/044TcIFl72
```

I have this formula which I was trying to adapt for it (not sure if it helps at all). I was trying to adapt this to use with =UNIQUE( ?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT($A$1:$A$15,18)=LEFT(A1,18)))>1
```

If it helps to take a look at the sheet, here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tG7TpHNvNY86PRiePsKyKfxnuEZah6T7ZDL7dXOIcEA/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added in the X's on the urls as you cant post shortened urls within a question...

Comment: what do you mean by unique up to Nth char? `Xttps://tXco/00lR1FNKBo` and `Xttps://tXco/00lR1Fw9cO` are both unique, but their first 17 chars are equal. So do you need to return only first one? If so, try `vlookup` of uniques.

Comment: sorry it wasnt that clear, yes uniques up to the 17 character. i can't work out how to do it with vlookup, knowledge on formulas isnt great. would you be able to explain further?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this formula:

`=ArrayFormula(vlookup(
  UNIQUE(FILTER(LEFT(A2:A,17),A2:A<>"")),
  FILTER({LEFT(A2:A,17),A2:A},A2:A<>""),
 2,0))`

---

## How it works

it will first find unique left N chars:

- `UNIQUE(FILTER(LEFT(A2:A,17),A2:A<>"")`

then get left N chars and original strings:

- `FILTER({LEFT(A2:A,17),A2:A},A2:A<>"")`

and then use `vlookup` to get top first entry for uniques.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead without the extra column. Put it in B1:

```
 =unique(arrayformula(if(left(A1:A,18)=left(A1:A,18),A1:A,"")))
```

Comment: Thanks for that, happy to have extra columns. I have tried it, column B works well, but column C doesnt have the right results (ive highlighted one example [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tG7TpHNvNY86PRiePsKyKfxnuEZah6T7ZDL7dXOIcEA/edit?usp=sharing) ) any chance you could take a look?

Comment: thanks, just tried but unfortunately doesnt work. this gives results in all complete uniques, not up to the 18th character. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: =unique(arrayformula(left(A1:A,18)))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).